# How to change interval dynamically with Observable pipe?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

Here is a method. `intervalValue` is updated with a button click. The value is changing frequently.

```
intervalValue: number; 
intervalValue: Observable<number>; // also tried this. but interval method is looking for a number 

  ngOnInit() {

    interval(intervalValue)
    .pipe( 
              debounceTime(150),
              distinctUntilChanged(),
              tap(() => { 
                    ... 
                }), 
              startWith({}),
        switchMap(() => { 
         ... 
        }),
        map(data => {
          ... 
          return data.content;
        }),
        catchError(() => {
         ... 
        })
        ).subscribe(data => this.data = data);
}
```

But when the `intervalValue` changes, the `interval` still at it's initial value. How can I make interval change when the value of `intervalValue` changes?

Comment: how is `intervalValue` being updated? In your code the `intervalValue` is one off, it take whatever that value is during `ngOnInit()` cycle, and then forget. If you want to listen to the `intervalValue` changes, it has to be either an `Observable` or a `Subject`

Comment: I tried making it as Observable: `intervalValue: Observable<number>` but got this error `Argument of type 'Observable<number>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'`

Comment: If you change `interval` as `Observable`, can't you just change - `interval(intervalValue.subscribe( i => { return i; })`

Comment: I tired that Argument of type 'Subscription' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to start with Intervalue stream

```
const intervalValue=of(Math.random()*10000)
intervalValue
    .pipe( 
              switchMap(time=>interval(time))
              debounceTime(150),
              distinctUntilChanged(),
              tap(() => { 
                    ... 
                }), 
              startWith({}),
        switchMap(() => { 
         ... 
        }),
        map(data => {
          ... 
          return data.content;
        }),
        catchError(() => {
         ... 
        })
        ).subscribe(data => this.data = data);
```

Comment: Thank you . Coudl you please elaborate. I don't understand how to implement it

Comment: I edited the code. Assume your intervalValue is a hot observable that changes value overtime, whenever it emit new value it will pass to the subsequent stream, and the new value will pickup by interval and process further down.

Comment: Thank you but i couldnt make it to work. `Cannot assign to 'intervalValue' because it is a constant`    but when i changed it to not constant still it doenst work

Comment: I tried this const `intervalValue=of(this.intervalValueInteger); 

          intervalValue 
    .pipe(  

      switchMap(time=>interval(time)),`

Comment: The same effect. interval doesnt change when the value of `this.intervalValueInteger` changes

Comment: in this case just use this.intervalValueInteger.pipe() directly. if you are returning an observable it is pipe pable

Comment: But `intervalValueInteger` is of type `number` and is not pipeable.

Comment: then use behaviour Subject. Observable cannot watch your variable change. intervalValueInteger=new BehaviourSubject() , intervalValueInteger.next(newValue) to change value